# Change key value and print both the changed value and the original value

Tags: json, jq

Just discoverd jq and I want to change the value of a key and print both the changed and original key value.

#### Original sample file

```
{
  "level": "info",
  "ts": 1587565958.8860734,
  "logger": "http.log.access.log0",
  "msg": "handled request",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "uri": "/info.php",
    "proto": "HTTP/1.1",
    "remote_addr": "192.168.0.92:42170"
    }
}
```

#### Filter

`.ts |= strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | .ts, .request[]`

#### output

```
"2020-04-22 14:32:38"
"GET"
"/info.php"
"HTTP/1.1"
"192.168.0.92:42170"
```

#### Required output

```
1587565958.8860734
"2020-04-22 14:32:38"
"GET"
"/info.php"
"HTTP/1.1"
"192.168.0.92:42170"
```

#### jq play

[jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/fyFUnYryUd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask and ye shall receive:

- adapting your query -

```
.ts,
(.ts |= strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | .ts, .request[])
```

- or more efficiently -

```
(.ts | ., strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
.request[]
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks.